# Tarot Metapuzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles

[image: Pentacles]

[image: Cups]

[image: Wands]

[image: Swords]

[image: A Minor Miracle]

(Imgur album for convenience: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqNfp.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Pentacles

> These are five crossword-like structures: the first two clues are for the outer and inner ring (the latter of which can read starting from any point and in any direction), and the remaining five clues are for the five sides of the pentagram.
>
>  The completed grids are here:
>  [image: completed grids with marked letters in red]
>  The red-dotted letters spell **STARFISH**.

### Cups

> Each of the right-hand phrases clues a different phrase - for instance, a "secretive buzzer" is a CAGEY BEE. This sounds like you're spelling out KGB, which fits the "espionage" clue.
>
>  The list of solutions is:
>
>  [image: KGB IDLE BAT SAIL BODS WE CLAD RUN NET]
>
>  In the image, some blanks for letters are circles instead of squares; the indicated letters spell **GLASSWARE**.

### Wands

> The clue answers are:
>  [image: clue answers]
>  Each of these can be parsed as a boolean expression - so "PANDA" is "P AND A". In some cases, the given order of operations disambiguates.
>
>  As hinted by the 26 rectangles, we need to figure out which of the letters is true and false. The clues highlighted yellow (green in my screenshot) are to be taken as true, and the rest are false.
>
>  The logic:
>
>  From FORD, GORU, JORD, LORD, VORW, WORX, QORE, HORRORCORE, [LANDF]ORM, KNORR, we rule out CDEFGHJKLMQRUVWX.
>  From ANANDA, A is true. From IXORA and PANDA, I and P are false.
>  From SANDS, S is false. From SNORT, T is true.
>  From BORG, B is true. From BANDZ, Z is false.
>  From NORMANDY, N is true. From NANDY, Y is false. From NOTHANDO, O is true.
>
>  Anagramming the true letters spells **BATON**, the "conductors' need" hinted in the flavortext.

### Swords

> Each of these clues is missing a certain number of letters from the front of all of its words:
>
>  ___ **O**n (**S**purred) (5)
>  "**HO**w **DO YO**u **LI**ke ___ **AP**ples?" (4)
>  **OCC**upying **AN OTT**oman, **PER**haps (6)
>  **PREP**ared **FOR A DECA**thlon, **FOR EXAM**ple (7)
>  **COMMO**nplace (8)
>  **YOU PLACE IT UNDERN**eath **A CHAMPA**gne **WINEGL**ass **TO COUNTE**ract **DISCOL**ouration **OF A TABLEC**loth, **E**. **G**. (7)
>
>  The answers to these clues are EGGED, THEM, SEATED, TRAINED, ORDINARY, and COASTER. Each of these can also have the appropriate number of letters added to the front to make a new word, forming **L**egged, **AN**them, **NAU**seated, **CONS**trained, **EXTRA**ordinary, **ROLLER**coaster.
>
>  The first letters of these spell **LANCER**.

### A Minor Miracle

> The given cards are the 4 of Cups, the 5 of Swords, the 4 of Swords, the 4 of Wands, the 4 of Pentacles, the 5 of Wands, the 5 of Swords (again), and the 6 of Swords.
>
>  Indexing into the corresponding answers spells **SE CORNER**.
>
>
>  In the bottom-right corner of the Rider-Waite-Smith deck (where these pictures are taken from), artist Pamela Coleman Smith drew a small 'signature'. But the signatures here have been edited - instead of merging together her initials, they each display a letter and a number.
>
>  [image: 5S 3P 4P 4S 3C 3S 3P 2C]
>
>  We can repeat the same process to get the final answer - tarot readers hear spirits with an **EAR CANAL** (which, as indicated by the pushed-up cards, has ARCANA right in the middle!)

<sup>Thanks to M Oehm and Stiv for helping me finish off this answer.</sup>

Comment: rot13(Lbhe zvffvat Phc vf VQYR, juvpu vf eryngrq gb zbenyvgl (fybgu). V guvax gur nzovthbhf bar fubhyq or ONG nf va 'ong fcbegf' - onfronyy, pevpxrg, rgp.)

Comment: Closer inspection reveals that rot13(gur fvtangher qvssref sebz pneq gb pneq. Vg vf abg gur hfhny CPF fvtangher sbhaq ba gur pneqf, ohg n ahzore-yrggre pbzovangvba. Lbh jvyy unir gb pbcl gur vzntr; whfg zntavslvat vg va vzthe vfa'g rabhtu, sbe zl rlrf ng yrnfg. Naljnl, qbvat gung tvirf RNE PNANY, juvpu svgf gur birenyy gurzr, orpnhfr vg unf Nepnan vafvqr.).

Comment: (And S3 could be rot13(anh | frngrq), I think.)

Comment: @Stiv Ah yes, that looks good - thanks! I didn't realize that second one as an actual phrase.

Comment: @MOehm Added both of those in, thanks for the help!